# Angles in Ptolemaic Model

Tags: observational-astronomy, history, mathematics, modeling, geocentrism

I am about to work with Ptolemy's Model for the motion of an upper Planet (Mars). I use a epicycle rolling on the deferent. As a first step, I am just interested in the shape of the trajectory, which is why I can ignore the equant, because the uniform motion arount the equant does not change the fact, that the epicycle rolls on the deferent, which is why $\phi_0^*$ can be expressed in terms of $\phi^*$, $r_A$ and $r_a$. I want to express the angle $\phi^*$ or $\phi_0^*$ in terms of $\gamma$. I assume $r_A$, $r_a$ and $c$ (distance from Earth A to the center of the deferent $B$ and distance from this center to the equant as well). How can I express $\phi^*$ geometrically?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood Ptolemy’s model: The epicycle doesn’t “roll on” the deferent; rather, the epicycle’s *center* is on deferent. Mind you, it’s only a minor detail in this situation.

In the diagram you drew up, it is impossible to know φ* in terms of γ alone, as φ₀ could take any value. Also, in Ptolemy’s model, φ₀ does *not* depend on φ*, so φ₀ ≠ δφ*. However, both vary uniformly, by quantities that we will here call ωₐ and ωₜ after Pedersen.¹ For example, in the case of Mars, ωₜ = 0°;31,26,36,53,51,33/day and ωₐ = 0°;27,41,40,19,20,58/day.

You are correct to presume that c, rₐ, and r<sub>A</sub> were known and specified in Ptolemy’s model—a good part of the *Almagest* is spent determining such values for rₐ and r<sub>A</sub> supposing that c = 60 units.

Finally, nowhere in the *Almagest* are φ* or φ₀ expressed in terms of γ, as both of them, as hinted two paragraphs above, are only time-dependent. Because none of the angular speeds given for ωₐ and ωₜ is a factor of 360°, this means that for a given γ, *any* value of φ* and φ₀ is possible, depending on how long has elapsed since the reference date (the “epoch”), which Ptolemy chooses, for historical reasons, to be February 26, −746 (aka 747 BCE), Noon Alexandria true solar time (Julian Day 1448637.91666…).

If you understand the language, I have translated the *Almagest* to French, with some diagrams animated or interactive. It’s freely available at https://ecliptiqc.ca.

---

¹Pedersen, O. *A Survey of the Almagest.* With Annotation and New Commentary by Alexander Jones. New York: Springer, 2011, 480 p., ISBN 978-0-387-84825-9.